# Creating an endpoint that lists _ids of a dataset

Tags: sesam

I want to create a dataset with only “_id” from another internal dataset. If I want to make this new dataset as small as possible, as this is only used as a list of all items in the former dataset. But then we get all underscore properties as well. Is there a way around this when pulling the data from Sesam?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by adding a layer between your dataset and the external client.

```
{
  "_id": "x",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "bar": "baz"
    }]
  }
}
```

This produces a dataset with a lot of internal variables (`_updated`, etc).

If external clients consume this dataset they get the dataset as-is.

Best practice is to not allow external clients to consume datasets directly, as this will make it harder to refactor your internal structure, but rather expose this data through an `http_endpoint`.

```
{
  "_id": "x-out",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "dataset",
    "dataset": "x"
  },
  "sink": {
    "type": "http_endpoint"
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["copy", "_id"]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following output from the `/api/publishers/x-out/entities` endpoint:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "foo"
  }
]
```